# Fresh installation of ElasticSearch 5.0.2 requires authentication - why?

Tags: security, authentication, elasticsearch

I am prompted for a user name and password after installing v5.0.2 - both for localhost:9200 and Kibana.

In reading the notes her: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/setting-up-authentication.html I tried executing the PUT commands through Fiddler but got 401 on each request - still needs auth.

I haven't set any user names or passwords and the only help online I can find relates to having installed Shield, which I have not installed.

Looking at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.0/setting-up-authentication.html#built-in-users, I am unable to issue requests to set the user names and passwords as authentication is required.

Suggestions please.

Comment: have you installed XPack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the default user and password:

> user: elastic
>
> password: changeme

This might be because xpack has users and roles . you can set up these in xpack.

read here :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html